# How FMDB makes sqlite more simpler iOS?

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, fmdb

i want to use fmdb in my iPhone application. What are the differences in using sqlite with fmdb without fmdb?

i need to be able to write queries.

how the fmdb is easier/effecient to use than single sqlite? if there is any source code or guide to it please post its link

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) is a wrapper on top of SQLite's C API with an API  more in Objective-C style. Which API style is "easier" is more up to you, it would depend greatly on your programming background and personal preference.

There's a guide showing how to use FMDB at [its GitHub page](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) which shows the API off pretty well, you should definitely read that before deciding.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson can I use fmdb for ios6

Comment: @VigneshKumar Yes, that should as afaik work without problems. Although I've not exhaustively tested it on myself (only minor test projects), there are patches added a few months ago to use it on ios6.

Answer (score 5):

It should also be noted that the author of sqlite (D. Richard Hipp) never intended the sqlite api to be used directly by programmers.  The idea was to create a low level API that higher level wrappers would use inside their applications (and I think that's largely why we see sqlite in just about everything these days!).

So even if you don't use FMDB, you should find another wrapper around SQLite.  Your life will be easier in the long run.