# Not able to update sqlite3 table iOS 5

Tags: ios5, ios6, sqlite, core-location

I am working on Core Location framework, trying to calculate distance between the coordinates and updating the distance onto the database(sqlite3.0). But for some reason i get redundant data getting updated. Im not sure if the code is correct for updating. I need some serious help guys. Thank you.

Here goes my code:

```
    if(sqlite3_open([writableDBPath UTF8String],&controller)==SQLITE_OK){
    NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from coordinate_table"];
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(controller, [str UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL);
    int i=0;

    while(sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW){
        newlat=sqlite3_column_double(statement, 0);
        newlongi=sqlite3_column_double(statement, 1);

        CLLocation *newLoc=[[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:newlat longitude:newlongi];

        CLLocationDistance dis=[currLoc distanceFromLocation:newLoc];

        NSString *dist=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",dis];





        [marr insertObject:dist atIndex:i];

        NSString *sql=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"update coordinate_table set distance=%f where latitude=%f and longitude=%f",dis,newlat,newlongi];
        NSLog(@"%@",sql);
        int res=sqlite3_exec(controller, [sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, NULL);

        NSLog(@"%d",res);
        i++;

    }
    NSLog(@"Distance Array %@",marr);
}
sqlite3_finalize(statement);
sqlite3_close(controller);
[tView reloadData];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend use [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) Lib for working with sqlite. It's powerful sqlite wrapper. It's simple for using! Look this question:

[How FMDB makes sqlite more simpler iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654733/how-fmdb-makes-sqlite-more-simpler-ios)

Hope I helps you)